# Remove bootstrap dropdown caret

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, caret

I'm working on my personal portfolio with bootstrap and the navigation dropdown has a caret as you can see at http://portfolio.tomvervoort.net.

The caret next to portfolio is ok but when you click on portfolio the dropdown also has a white caret on top. Does anyone knows how to remove this one?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your **caret** is inside `.dropdown-menu:after`. So, write like this:

```
.navbar .dropdown-menu:after{
 display:none;
}
```

Comment: In the latest version of TBS, you also need to add: .navbar .dropdown-menu:before{ display:none; }. See my answer for full code.

Answer (score 5):

Had the same problem in Rails (with twitter bootstrap rails gem), and the fix was slightly different.

```
.navbar .nav > li > .dropdown-menu::after, 
.navbar .nav > li > .dropdown-menu::before {
  display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In the current version of TBS (v2.2.1), you also need to target the :before pseudo-selector like so:

```
.navbar .dropdown-menu:after, .navbar .dropdown-menu:before {
    display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this:

```
.navbar .nav > li > .dropdown-menu:before,
.navbar .nav > li > .dropdown-menu:after {
    display:none;
}
```

works fine for me. :-)

Answer (score 0):

from git hub [post](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/pull/343)
now we can directly use `noCaret` prop. this post is basically from DropDownButton but it works for NAvButton as well

Answer (score 0):

After trying a few solutions and trying to follow the right class references, a quick fix, but nest it if you can so it doesn't affect other global `a` tags:

```
a::after {
    content: none !important;
}
```